# Celery + Django

Tags: django, task, celery

У меня на бэкенде есть функционал оповещений. Раз в час скрип проходит по записям в БД и обновляет информацию по товарам. Если определенная информация изменилась (Это может быть цена или остаток на складе), то создается таск на оповещение, пример:

```
# создания таска для оповещения пользователю
if price != self.price:
    check_notifications.delay(poduct_id=self.pk, old_price=self.price, new_price=price)
```

В самом таске формируется сообщение на почту для определённой группы пользователей, исходя из полученных данных.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Товаров более 1млн, остаток может меняться часто и получается что раз в час почта разрывается от количества сообщений.

Какое решения я вижу: формирования списка товаров, у которых изменилась информация, по завершении скрипта формируется уже одно сообщение в котором скажем 1000 товаров, а не 1000 раздельных сообщений

Как в celery сформировать список тасков с каким-нибудь пояснением или флагом, который будет их объединять? Как такой список передать в функцию для создания сообщения? Как после завершения скрипта вызывать функцию, которая объединит информацию из всех тасков?

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: Как-то сложно. Зачем создавать список тасков, если можно просто создать список изменившихся товаров и потом обработать весь этот список в одной-единственной таске, которая сформирует из этого списка одно-единственное письмо? Что-то типа `check_notifications_for_many_products.delay(products=products_list)`

Comment: А где хранить этот список?

Comment: А как у вас обрабатывается изменение информации? Я подразумевал, что в начале вашего скрипта можно создать переменную со списком, потом пройтись по всем товарам и заполнить список, а в конце скрипта запустить таск с этим готовым списком. Но, возможно, я что-то не понял и ваш скрипт устроен более сложно?

Comment: Получается информация о товаре в json, для примера:
{"articul":"123", "qty":10, "price":1000}

Выбирается товар из базы по артикулу. У товара есть метод, который принимает json и обновляет информацию по текущему экземпляру. Для размерных товаров все чуть сложнее, к ним привязана таблица размеров, но смысл остается тот же. Если какой-либо параметр изменился, то запускается таск с нужными параметрами, уже внутри него формируется сообщение.

Comment: У вас таск запускается внутри метода товара? Если да, то, наверное, лучше таск не создавать, а вместо этого вернуть (return) информацию об изменившихся данных (например в виде словаря), тогда скрипт сможет собрать эти данные в один список и затем запустить один таск

Comment: К примеру. Обновилось 1000 товаров. Могу ли я в redis создать структуру данных: {"product_id": "123", "old_price": 2000, "new_price":1000}

И после выполнения скрипта пройтись по redis в поисках изменившихся товаров и на их основе сделать список

Comment: Да, наверное так будет лучше, но в таком случае придется много чего переписать. Спасибо за совет!

Comment: Вообще в Redis вроде как [тоже есть списки](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-1-getting-started/chapter-1-getting-to-know-redis/1-2-what-redis-data-structures-look-like/1-2-2-lists-in-redis/) (RPUSH, LRANGE, LTRIM) да и множества тоже, но лично мне такое решение кажется архитектурно не очень красивым

Answer (score 0):

Проще создать например модель message и fk на пользователя или группу. И в celery просто создавать запись в message. А потом уже отдельным таском бежать по пользователям и отдельным таском отправлять все сообщения разом пользователю или группе. Если надо можно их тут же удалять, чтобы не засорять БД